# Click the pixel with the coordinates x, y Javascript

Tags: javascript, click, coordinates

I need to write a Javascript program that clicks at the coordinate (x, y). I have tried document.elementFromPoint(x, y).click() but it doesn't work because there is no element there. Is there any other method?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add an EventListener to the document:

```
document.addEventListener("click", myClickHandler);
```

Then you can receive the point of click using you handler method, like this:

```
function myClickHandler(event) {
  console.log("X: " + event.clientX + " Y: " + event.clientY)
}
```

Comment: thanks but i need the program to click at the coordinate, not to tell me the coordinates in case of a click